# Why via manual impex import I have a good result but if I invoke update I haven't result

Tags: import, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I notice that if I invoke any impex files manually(console -> impex import) - it is working. But if I make update system, I haven't success. In the log I see that this file mentions. Am I misunderstanding this situation?

log:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.633 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] [AbstractSystemSetup] Begin SOLR index setup [hybris]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.634 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/merchandisecore/import/stores/hybris/solr.impex]...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.635 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] [DefaultImportService] Starting import synchronous using cronjob with code=000000SL
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.637 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [ImpExImportJob] Starting ImpEx cronjob "ImpEx-Import"
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.638 | WARN  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [HeaderDescriptor] line 28 at main script: column mode of type SolrServerConfig is not writable, but you want to update it. If you want to write this non writable attribute explicit, you have to use the forceWrite=true modifier. This warning is printed only once for header. Please check subsequent lines for similar problem.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.752 | WARN  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [HeaderDescriptor] line 125 at main script: column type of type SolrIndexerQuery is not writable, but you want to update it. If you want to write this non writable attribute explicit, you have to use the forceWrite=true modifier. This warning is printed only once for header. Please check subsequent lines for similar problem.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.757 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [Importer] Finished 1 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:098ms - processed: 73, dumped: 3 (last pass: 0)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.860 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [Importer] Starting pass 2
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.860 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] (000000SL) [Importer] Finished 2 pass in 0d 00h:00m:00s:006ms - processed: 3, no lines dumped (last pass 3)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.862 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] [DefaultImportService] Import was successful (using cronjob with code=000000SL)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/12/09 12:44:41.963 | INFO  [hybrisHTTP26] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [/merchandisecore/import/stores/hybris/solr_en.impex]...
```

Comment: are you sure you have checked respected fields when updating system through HAC?

Comment: yes. I have checked it.

Comment: in log looks that this file (*/merchandisecore/import/stores/hybris/solr.impex**)  
is processing

Comment: Hybris is adopting the Convention over configuration principle, to simplify or eradicate the need for writing configuration files. During the initialization and update processes platform looks for ImpEx files in extension_name/resources/impex.

Comment: can someone tell me where to find the impex cron job logs?

Comment: @user1058511- Impex cron job logs can be found under HMC> System> Cronjobs > (Search for your cron job)> Under the Log tab of the cron job screen> Log files.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there are some columns on the type you're trying to update which need add the forceWrite=true on the impex header.

Some attributes are not writables once they are created.

I do not know how the impex you're trying to execute are,but I would try to delete the item, and then check if the impex is executed correctly on the update (but do not execute the impex first on the hac import impex).